# Connect Apache Flink with Apache kudu as sink using Pyflink

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kudu, pyflink

I am kind of new to Flink and I need to connect an Apache Flink streaming to Apache Kudu as sink

1. the source is a CSV file with X records that has been read from the filesystem
2. the source is a Kafka connector (create a table using Kafka connector and CSV format.)

it needs to be in Python (pyflink)
can someone help me with a basic example of it or a guild? the docs lack this info related to KUDU.